# Entity Add/Insert with column equal to identity primary key value

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

During an insert/add can I make a different column equal to the newly valued primary key that's an identity auto generated value all in one write/save process? I know I can grab after fact and change but that's extra database hits I'm trying to avoid.

```
public class myDataTableRec
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    //This is an Identity Primary Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }  //Want this the same as Id when it gets generated
}


myrec = new myDataTableRec;
db.myDataTable.Add(myrec);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The main question is: ***why*** would you want to store the same value in two separate variables of your object? Doesn't really make a lot of sense, it seems..... and the only way to do this "properly" would be to have a **trigger** on your database table after an `INSERT`, that would also set the `PostId` to the newly inserted identity value.

Comment: Was trying to have this one table store a master record and detail since they have same columns. Having all the master and detail grouped with same id as the master identity record. Maybe this isn't good architecture.  So the postid would only be the same on the master record,  If I leave in one db, then one read grabs it all vs two dbs.

Comment: Would it perhaps be easier to make the rule as "if parent is is null then it's the master record"

Comment: That wouldn't allow me to grab all master/detail recs with one pull which is the goal.  I'm going to rethink my strategy.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the property of `StoreGeneratedPattern` to identity and then you'll be able to achieve this

```
 myrec = new myDataTableRec;
 db.myDataTable.Add(myrec);
 db.SaveChanges();
 var id = myrec.Id;
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid reading the id back, then setting my PostId = id, and doing another save.  That requires two saves on the Database.  Wanted only one.  Is it possible?

Comment: It seems like you want a custom id generated by yourself, if that is the case, remove the autogenerated from the column in the DB and let yourself control it.

Comment: Was trying to have this one table store a master record and detail since they have same columns.  Having all the master and detail grouped with same id as the master identity record.    Maybe this isn't good architecture. Not sure.

Answer (score 2):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?view=efcore-5.0

"Add(TEntity)

Begins tracking the given entity, and any other reachable entities that are not already being tracked, in the Added state such that they will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges() is called.

Use State to set the state of only a single entity."

Since it tracks the entity, you can do the following:

```
        myrec=new myDataTableRec;
        db.myDataTable.Add(myrec);
        myrec.PostId = myrec.Id
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Edit: If it creates the Id after the Save, the you can always create your own Id (Guid.NewGuid()) and don't let EF generate it.

Comment: You clearly didn't test this.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it's not possible to insert an entity and set its generated primary in a foreign key column to itself in one atomic operation. That's only possible if the primary key is not generated, i.e. not an identity column.

However, just as EF is capable of inserting related entities in one operation and setting generated key values in foreign keys on the fly, one might argue that EF could support setting a parent to itself.

Take this entity class (replacing your placeholder name and enhancing it with navigation properties):

```cs
class Post
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentPostID { get; private set; }

    public Post ParentPost { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> ChildPosts { get; private set; }
}
```

EF *could* have chosen to support this scenario:

```cs
using var db = new MyContext();
var root = new Post { Name = "Root" };
root.ParentPost = root;
db.Set<Post>().Add(root);
```

But it doesn't. It tries to insert the entity with a `ParentPostID` equal to the temporary (negative) `ID` value. Obviously, that's a FK violation.

To do this cleanly you have to add a transaction and set & save the self reference separately:

```cs
using var db = new MyContext();
var root = new Post { Name = "Root" };
db.Set<Post>().Add(root);

using var ts = new TransactionScope();
db.SaveChanges();
root.ParentPost = root;
db.SaveChanges();
ts.Complete();
```

Note that the parent id has to be nullable. Also note that the navigation property allows setting the parent without ever knowing its key value. Some people like to do these things in a DDD style.